# How to replace strings in a dataframe where there is a likely typo

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, levenshtein-distance

I been working on this for a few hours but no progress on how to automate.  I have a dataframe with over 50,000 rows.

Occasionally there is a misspelling like

- Rosalind vs Rosalinda
- Wong vs Wang

Of course there can be cases where there is lets say indeed two different people but lets assume that they work in different factories

- John Wong from Factory1
- John Wang from Factory1 -> Should be changed to John Wong
- John Wang from Factory2

**Without manually finding all the typos, how do I clean this dataset or atleast identify likely typos?**

So the dataframe would go from

DF1

```
  Lname    Fname     Location
  Wong     John      Factory1
  Wang     John      Factory1
  Wong     Joh       Facotry1
  Wang     John      Factory2
```

to something like

```
   Lname   Fname     Location
   Wong    John      Factory1
   Wong    John      Factory1
   Wong    John      Factory1
   Wang    John      Factory2
```

Is something like this possible?  Thanks

Edit: fixed typo in the location

Comment: Is `Facotry1` a typo or intended? :)

Comment: How do you identify which word is a typo `Wong` or `Wang`? Do you have a wordlist? While standard words can be identified using a genric wordlist, what about proper nouns?

Comment: Facotry1 is indeed a typo.

Comment: @aiden `Facotry1` is still in the first dataframe - is _that_ intended?

Comment: There are too many first and last name combos it is too hard to generate a word list.  I thought about using levenshtein distance to solve this but it is so hard